# Hard reboot causes MySQL replication to break

Tags: mysql-replication

I have encountered an issue with my replication setup. Under normal circumstances it performs as intended, but it breaks if it encounters a hard reboot (I pull the power cable).

### Setup

The setup consists of two servers, **server-1** and **server-2**. The replication setup is a circular replication. Both servers are slaves replicating from the other host as if it were the master.

#### Software

- Red Hat 6.5
- MySQL 5.1.73-3
- MySQL-libs 5.1.73-3
- MySQL-server 5.1.73-3

#### Redundancy configuration

The replication configuration is as follows for **server-1**, and is mirrored for **server-2**:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicant';
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;"

#Use "SHOW MASTER STATUS \G;" to determine log position and log file

UNLOCK TABLES;

# set status on slave server using the values retieved earlier
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='server-2', MASTER_USER='replicant', MASTER_LOG_FILE='[log file]', MASTER_LOG_POS=[log pos];"

START SLAVE;
```

### Error information

This information is retrieved when the **server-2** has encountered a hard reboot and the replication is broken.

#### server-1 slave status

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: server-2
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: bin.000004
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 37550
               Relay_Log_File: relay.000427
                Relay_Log_Pos: 245
        Relay_Master_Log_File: bin.000004
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 37550
              Relay_Log_Space: 529
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
```

#### server-2 slave status

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: server-1
                  Master_User: replicant
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 7208
               Relay_Log_File: relay.000010
                Relay_Log_Pos: 245
        Relay_Master_Log_File: bin.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 7208
              Relay_Log_Space: 529
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
```

#### Relevant information from server-2 mysql-log-error.log

These logs are from the boot that caused the replication to fail

```
150821 12:52:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150821 12:52:35  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
150821 12:52:35  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
150821 12:52:35  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 106, file name /var/lib/mysql/bin.000002
150821 12:52:35  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 259987
150821 12:52:35 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/lib/mysql/bin
150821 12:52:35 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
150821 12:52:35 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
150821 12:52:35 [ERROR] log  listed in the index, but failed to stat
150821 12:52:35 [ERROR] Error counting relay log space
150821 12:52:35 [ERROR] Failed to initialize the master info structure
150821 12:52:35 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150821 12:52:35 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

#### Replicant access

Among the things that I attempted in order to gather information and resolve the issue, was to attempt to access **server-1** from **server-2** on behalf of the **replicant** user. That attempt was not successful, and I got an "*Access denied*" message.

I therefore looked into grants on **server-2**, and got the following information.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR "replicant"@"server-1";
ERROR 1141 (42000) at line 1: There is no such grant defined for user 'replicant' on host 'server-1;'
```

### My attempts at finding a resolution

My attempts to solve this problem have so far been fruitless. No matter what I try, I always get the same answer from MySQL.

```
ERROR 1201 (HY000) at line 1: Could not initialize master info structure; more error messages can be found in the MySQL error log
```

Any configuration, FLUSH, RESET, or log manipulation that I have tried has resulted in this error message when I then attempt to either "*START SLAVE;*" or "*CHANGE MASTER TO ...*", to get the replication going again.

#### Duplicating server-1

Making **server-2** a copy of **server-1** is promising. I get **server-2** working, but **server-1** is unable to replicate from **server-2**. I copy the server using the following steps.

1. stop the mysqld service on **server-2**
2. Clear */var/lib/mysql/* on **server-2**
3. rsync */var/lib/mysql/* from **server-1** to **server-2**
4. change master host on **server-2** to be *server-1*
5. start the mysqld service on **server-2**

It looks like this does the trick **server-2**, but **server-1** is unable to replicate from **server-2**. I see the following in the slave status of **server-1**:

```
  Slave_IO_state: Waiting to reconnect after a failed master even read
Slave_IO_Running: No
```

I find this in the error logs on **server-1**

```
[Note] Slave I/O thread: Failed reading log event, reconnecting to retry, log 'FIRST' at position 4
[ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Access denied; you need the REPLICATION SLAVE privilege for this operation ( server_errno=1227)
```

I have checked the grants for the **replicant** user on both servers, and they have not changed.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'replicant';
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replicant@%                            |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicant'@'%' |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems like **server-1** is having problems accessing the logs on **server-2**. I have attempted the following to fix this problem.

- *RESET MASTER;* + *RESET SLAVE;* on both servers, and then setting up the slaves again using *CHANGE MASTER TO ...;*.
- Changing the **MASTER_LOG_FILE** and **MASTER_LOG_POS** on **server-1** before the **rsync** to match the master status of **server-1**.
- Trying every permutation of **MASTER_LOG_FILE** and **MASTER_LOG_POS** manipulation that I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I continued working on the problem, and put together a solution that worked for me.

### Solution

This solution assumes that **server-2** is the server with the broken replication. This solution needs to be mirrored if **server-1** is the server that is broken.

1. Disable incoming connections on both servers

   - *SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;* should only show a **localhost** connection with "SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST" state, and perhaps some **system user** entries
   - One way of achieving this is to assign a new port to the mysql service that is not the default 3306, or if you are specifying a port, change it to something else.

     - E.g. add "**port=33060**" to the **[mysqld]** section in */etc/my.cnf*
2. Prevent the replication slave process from starting when the server starts, on both servers

   1. Add "**skip-slave-start**" to the **[mysqld]** section in */etc/my.cnf*
   2. Restart the mysql server

      - *service mysqld restart*
3. Reset slave and master configurations on **server-1**

   - *RESET SLAVE;*
   - *RESET MASTER;*
4. Create a copy of the database on **server-1**, and copy it to **server-2**.

   1. *FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;*
   2. *mysqldump --databases [replicated database] ... > ./dump.sql*
   3. *UNLOCK TABLES;*
   4. *scp ./dump.sql [user]@server-2:/home/[user]/*
5. Import the data into the database on **server-2**

   - As root, *mysql < /home/[user]/dump.sql*
6. Reset slave and master configurations on **server-2**

   - *RESET SLAVE;*
   - *RESET MASTER;*
7. Configure the replication slave on both servers

   - On **server-1**: *CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='server-2', MASTER_USER='replicant', MASTER_LOG_FILE="bin.000001", MASTER_LOG_POS=1;*
   - On **server-2**: *CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='server-1', MASTER_USER='replicant', MASTER_LOG_FILE="bin.000001", MASTER_LOG_POS=1;*
8. If you receive the following error on **server-2**: *ERROR 1201 (HY000): Could not initialize master info structure; more error messages can be found in the MySQL error log*

   - Remove the relay mysql relay files, and attempt steps **6** and **7** again.
   - *rm -rf /var/lib/relay**
9. Enable incoming connections on both servers

   - Revert step **1**
   - Restart the mysql server

     - *service mysqld restart*
10. Start replication slaves on both servers

    - *START SLAVE;*
11. Replication should now be working. Verify its health on both servers

    - *SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;*

      - **Slave_IO_State** should not indicate an error
      - **Slave_IO_Running** and **Slave_SQL_Running** should both be in **Yes** state
12. Clean up

    - Remove **skip-slave-start** entry from */etc/my.cnf* on both servers

      - It is not necessary to restart the mysql server
    - Delete the **dump.sql** file on both servers